# Envio de arquivos para o google drive com .net

Tags: c#, .net

Como enviar um arquivo para o google drive em c#?
Eu tenho um IntPtr de um arquivo, tenho que converter para bytes e fazer o envio?
Como ficaria o envio? Peguei um código deu m tutorial, porem não entendi quais as configs:

```
class DriveCommandLineSample
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
        String CLIENT_SECRET = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";

        // Register the authenticator and create the service
        var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);
        {
            Authenticator = auth
        });

        File body = new File();
        body.Title = "My document";
        body.Description = "A test document";
        body.MimeType = "text/plain";

        byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("document.txt");
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
        request.Upload();

        File file = request.ResponseBody;
        Console.WriteLine("File id: " + file.Id);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
    {
        // Get the auth URL:
        IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue() });
        state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
        Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

        // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
        Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
        Console.Write("  Authorization Code: ");
        string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
        return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
    }
}
```

}

Esse cliente ID , e secret refere a que? em qual pasta vou enviar lá?

Comment: De uma olhada no `SDK` do drive para `C#` -> https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-cs

Comment: Neste site tem um tutorial sobre isso -> http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-upload/

Comment: De acordo com o que você postou montei o codigo na pergunta, ver se voce pode me ajudar. vlw

Comment: Básicamente são os dados para acessar a `API` realizar a autenticação. Na documentação do `SDK` explica como fazer isso. -->https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server

Comment: no link do `daimto.com` tem a série de tutoriais, da uma olhada em todas as partes da série sobre o `Google Drive`.

Comment: A biblioteca google drive não instala no visual studio 2012, pq pede a versão do nuget mais nova, e so tem pra 2013, sabe onde posso encontrar a .dll ja compilada?

Comment: Desconheço, já tento atualiza o `NuGet`?

Comment: é pelo nuget q estou tentando, pede a versão mais nova...

Comment: Baixa e instala a versão mais nova do nuget e instala no VS2012. Olhei no site e a versão mais nova do nuget roda no VS2012.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24912/discussion-between-war-lock-and-meuchapeu).

Comment: Consegui vlw...

Comment: ALguem sabe me falar pq está parando no request.upload() ? não lança exceção nem nada. cria o diretorio porem nada de arquivo